# Child control naming standard changed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, controls

I have a JavaScript function on an ASP.NET page that will check all the boxes in a grid on the client side when a 'Check All' checkbox is checked in the grid header.   It does this by constructing the actual control ID in the JS function for each row in a loop (i.e.  + '_*ctl' + i + '*' +  where i is the row index of the current loop) and then setting the resulting control to checked.

This has worked fine for a long time but now it has stopped working, and the reason is that the .NET rendering engine or whatever is creating the internal control ID's differently.  For example, when viewing the source of the page on a different server where this is still working, the control name is **dgMain__ctl2_cbxChecked**, but the control name on the server where this is NOT working is **dgMain__ctl02_cbxChecked**.   The difference is that there is an extra '**0**' stuck in front of the numeric ID in the 'ctl' part on the version that is NOT working.

I am wondering if this has to do with the version of .NET?   It is not working on my local machine which is relatively new (used to work on an older machine), but it still works on an older server where it is deployed in production.   Both versions are running ASP.NET 1.1 (yeah I know - get with the times).

Any clues on how to resolve this?

Comment: Simple solution, don't use IDs. Use class names and `[data-*]` attributes to pass data to JavaScript. It'll allow you to keep your script in its own JS file rather than trying to build a script within an HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly dangerous practice. You should instead collect the resulting control `ClientID`s server side and then pass them to your JavaScript using the `ClientScriptManager`. Another approach would be to use the `CssClass` and use jQuery or some other DOM manipulation library to find your controls.

The control naming conventions are such that the ID is not guaranteed. It could change from .NET version to version (although unlikely) and it can change based on other controls on the page or nesting level of user controls etc.